# DIV and SPAN - Block and inline qus. Please help on this

Tags: css

I want to align the text as follows using DIV and SPAN but couldnt:

ABC1 ABC2 
XYZ1 XYZ2

My HTML with internal CSS is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> This is Page Title </title>
<style>
 span {display:block;}
 div {display:inline;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="x">
<span class="a">ABC1</span>
<span class="a">XYZ1</span>
</div>

<div class="y">
<span class="b">ABC2</span>
<span class="b">XYZ2</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and its output is as follows:
ABC1
XYZ1
ABC2
XYZ2

Would appreciate any help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the CSS to

```
<style>
   span {display:block;}
   div {display:inline; float:left}
</style>
```

Comment: @user1714297 - How does this answer what you asked for http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5HNYP/1/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5HNYP/)**

```
.x {
    float:left;
}
span {
    display:block;
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making the div inline-block [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/bBr4K/).

Comment: Ah, but it will! Check out [this link](http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/) for the *zoom IE inline-block fix

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/GCJrd/21/)

```
.x{
 width:50px;
float:left;
display:inline:block;
}
.y{
 width:50px;
float:left;
display:inline:block;
}
```